# Unable to resolve circular reference issue with JPA and REST Controller in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm working on a `@RestController` class that should return a JSON data with `Teacher` and array of 1 or more `Section`s handled.

*I currently have only 2 distinct records in the `teacher_section` table*

I believe the relationship is :

- **1** `Teacher` can have **MANY** handled `Section`(s)
- **1** `Section` can be handled by **MANY** different `Teacher`(s)

Which made me think that the correct relationship annotation to use is `@ManyToMany`

**Database tables**

```
CREATE TABLE `teacher_section` (
  `teacher_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `section_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `teacher_id` (`teacher_id`),
  KEY `section_id` (`section_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `teacher_section_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`teacher_id`) REFERENCES `teacher` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `teacher_section_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `section` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='This is a join table';

CREATE TABLE `teacher` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `is_adviser` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `is_active` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `section` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `section_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Java classes below.

**AbstractEntity**

```
@MappedSuperclass 
public class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="is_active")
    private boolean isActive;

//getters and setters....
}
```

**Teacher**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="teacher")
public class Teacher extends AbstractEntity{
    
    @Column(name="employee_id")
    private int employeeId;
    
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="middle_name")
    private String middleName;
    
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="is_adviser")
    private boolean isAdviser;
    
    @Column(name="date_created")
    private Timestamp dateCreated;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
        })
    @JoinTable(
              name = "teacher_section", 
              joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id"), 
              inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "section_id"))
    Set<Section> sections;

    //getters and setters.....
}
```

**Section**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="section")
public class Section extends AbstractEntity{
    
    @Column(name = "section_name")
    private String sectionName;
    
    @ManyToMany (mappedBy = "sections")
    private Set<Teacher> teachers;

    //getters and setters...
}
```

**TeacherRestController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/teachers")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class TeacherRestController {

    @Autowired
    TeacherRepository teacherRepository;
    
    
    @GetMapping
    public List<Teacher> getTeachers(){
        //GET localhost:8080/grading/teachers
        return teacherRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**TeacherRepository**

```
public interface TeacherRepository extends JpaRepository<Teacher, Long>{

}
```

**PROBLEM**

The endpoint **GET** `localhost:8080/grading/teachers` returns json data which nested `Teacher` within `Section` multiple times.

The response in Postman looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "employeeId": 20210001,
        "firstName": "John",
        "middleName": "Someone",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "dateCreated": "2021-08-29T13:13:29.000+00:00",
        "adviser": false,
        "section": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "sectionName": "Unity",
                "teacher": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "employeeId": 20210001,
                        "firstName": "John",
                        "middleName": "Someone",
                        "lastName": "Doe",
                        "dateCreated": "2021-08-29T13:13:29.000+00:00",
                        "adviser": false,
                        "section": [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "sectionName": "Unity",
                                "teacher": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 1,
                                        "employeeId": 20210001,
                                        "firstName": "John",
                                        "middleName": "Someone",
                                        "lastName": "Doe",
                                        "dateCreated": "2021-08-29T13:13:29.000+00:00",
                                        "adviser": false, .....
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. I even tried to follow some online guides on how to properly implement the @ManyToMany from the 2 websites below but still unable to solve the issue.

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

I am using Spring Tool Suite IDE and MySQL as database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to decide which relationship you want to serialize.  Please read https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: You need `@JsonIdentityInfo`, or better, a separate DTO representation.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli thank you for sharing the reference. It has a lot of information I don't know about yet.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- The `@JsonIdentityInfo` solved my problem! Thanks a lot!! I'll read more about the annotations related to Json and experiment alternatives.

Comment: Don't use the entity objects in the controller this is very bad practice. Create separate dto objects and the map entities.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotations. The first one on the owning root object, and the second one in the child object.

in Teacher:

```
@JsonManagedReference
Set<Section> sections;
```

in Section:

```
@JsonBackReference
private Set<Teacher> teachers;
```

The alternative is to add `@JsonIgnore` to the `teachers` field in `Section`.